# Why is my Visibility binding not working?

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, combobox, textbox

I have a problem with one of my Visibility Bindings.
In my application I have a Textbox and a combobox at nearly the same place.
They are overlapping so I have two Variables in the background for their Visibility. They are in a Datagrid, so the Visibility Source will be provided from the list.

The Binding of my Combobox works absolutely fine, but the one of my Textbox doesn't

Here is my Code:

```
<TextBox    x:Name="Textvalue" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center" 
            Width="150" 
            BorderBrush="#FF383F55" 
            BorderThickness="0" 
            Foreground="White" 
            Background="#FF232734"
            Text="{Binding Path=Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
            Visibility="{Binding Path=IsPath}"/>

<ComboBox   x:Name="Combobox" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center" 
            Foreground="White" 
            Margin="3,3,3,3" 
            Height="23"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ValueArray}" 
            SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
            Style="{DynamicResource ComboBoxStyle1}" 
            Visibility="{Binding Path=IsCombobox}"/>
```

These are my Get Property for both (Both only have the Get Proberty):

```
public System.Windows.Visibility isPath
{
    get
    {
        return _IsPath;
    }
}

public System.Windows.Visibility IsCombobox
{
    get
    {
        return _IsCombobox;
    }
}
```

I hope you can help me because I don't know what's wrong here :/
Thanks in advance

What I have tried:

Tried to change the binding to a different Variable.

Comment: Is Vievmodel bound correctly? Did you try to put the breakpoint in `IsCombobox` property and see if it's reached?

Comment: Use Visibility="{Binding IsCombobox}" instead of Visibility="{Binding Path=IsCombobox}"

Comment: The property name in your code has a lower case 'i' `public System.Windows.Visibility isPath` and the XAML has an upper case I in binding `IsPath`.

Comment: I agree with @CS but I'd also add, have you looked into the [boolean-to-visibility converter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that is provided. Allows you to simply bind to a `bool` on the VM and have the converter take care of modifying this to a `Visibility`, means you don't have to worry about what I see as view specific items in the VM.

Comment: It was exactly the thing "C S" said. Pretty disappointing that i couldn't figure it out myself :/ Thanks a lot! 
@StephenRoss No I didn't look into the converter but I will. Thank you.
is there a way to accept "C S" solution as answer in a comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property name in your code has a lower case 'i' public System.Windows.Visibility isPath and the XAML has an upper case I in binding IsPath. Change this and it should be working!

{Credit C S, I'd already started writing this}